# Google Page Speed Insights not recognising WP-Cofig settings?

Tags: pages, wp-config

I have been using Google Page Speed to help try speed up my site, which it rates pretty poorly.

Google suggest I Enable Compression and Minify. Well, these are defined in my WP-Config file. So either Google is not recognizing these are on, or the WP-Config isn't working?

Which should I trust?

[image]

Comment: You can look in the Network tab of Chrome developer tools and see the response headers, this will tell you if files are gzipped or deflated. I would first verify if the server is properly configured to use gzip.

Answer (score 2):

The `enfoce_gzip` constant, and the other in the same group in your config, actually refer to how wordpress should serve admin side related JS and CSS, and it seems like you are interested in the front end.

Setting gzip compression is something that you should do in your server configuration level (several options depending on the server, but for apache you will probably do it in the .htaccess file), the reason is that most files being served - CSS, JS, images, do not pass though wordpress code at all and therefor wordpress can not have any influence on how they are being served.

Answer (score 0):

Gzip compression is defined at server level, not in wp

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/100111)

Comment: @tfrommen, it is not a great answer but IMO sometimes there is just nothing more to say than one sentence.